# Local variable referenced before assginment (not making sense...)

Tags: python

So I wrote this fragment of code inside one of my projects, and defined n to be a boolean value True. Then, I used it to make a toggle case of a pause/resume button. For some reason, I get the error for using n in the if statement before allegedly assigning it inside the if and else code, although I already assigned it above the whole function.

Can somebody explain this error? And maybe suggest a way to fix it?

```
n = True

    def pauseresume():
        if n:
            pauseb.configure(text="Resume")
            n = False
        else:
            pauseb.configure(text="Pause")
            n = True
```

Comment: It's a scope problem. `pauseresume` needs to explicitely use `global n`, or have it as argument.

Comment: either pass it in the function or declare it as a global var.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a global variable, you need to explicitely use it via `global` keyword.

```py
n = True

def pauseresume():
  global n
  pauseb.configure(text="Resume" if n else "Pause")
  n = not n  # switch to other bool value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use global var in a function
solution:

```
def pauseresume():
    global n

    if n:
    ...
```

For detail, click
[Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function/423596#423596).